# (PHP) 'If ' statement only echos out one side, it changes to the 'else' and changes back to the 'if' based off of which product is added to the cart

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, if-statement, foreach

I'm going to start by telling you my desired outcome for the code: I want to echo to screen a sale price (if the product is in the sale in the database table), and a usual price (if the product is not in the sale in the database table).

I have tried to create an if statement, which I will outline underneath.

First things first: I establish a variable for the product table to use later on in the `if` statement.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ''";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

To preface this, I created an array from submitted form data:

```
$_SESSION['shoppingcart'][0] = array (

        'id' => filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'ID'),
        'price' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'hidden_price'),
        'list_price' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'hidden_list_price'),
        'quantity' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'quantity'),

         );
```

Then I create another array that singles out the `id` column in the `$_SESSION['shoppingcart']` array.

```
$product_ids = array();
$product_ids = array_column($_SESSION['shoppingcart'], 'id');
```

So, now I want to loop through the `$productids` array with a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach ($_SESSION['shoppingcart'] as $key => $cartprod): ?>
```

Now comes the `if` statement that I have been struggling with:

(just to add, `$row['sale]` is the column that I have as either 'yes' - for in the sale - or 'no' - for not in the sale.)

```
      <?php if ($row['sale'] == "yes"){
          echo '<td>£'.$cartprod['list_price'].'</td>';
              }else{
                  echo '<td>£'.$cartprod['price'].'</td>';
       }?>

    <?php endforeach;?>
        <?php endif;?>
```

So if I add a product to the `array` that is in the sale, it works fine, I can add them and it will `echo` out the `$cartprod['list_price']` all day long, and vice versa - I can add products that are not in the sale to the array and it will `echo` out the `$cartprod['list_price']`.

The trouble comes when I try to add a product to the `array` that is in the sale along with a product that is not in the sale. Its one or the other, I can't have a variety of sale and none-sale products in the `array`.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you if you read this far :).

Comment: You are currently looping through `$_SESSION['shoppingcart']` not the `$product_ids` variable

Comment: WARNING: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern development framework like Laravel comes with a robust authentication system built-in.

Comment: You should really consider my above comment or at the very least use prepared statements rather than accessing the database directly.

Comment: How is `$row['sale']` related to the items in `$_SESSION['shoppingcart']`?

Comment: The code shown doesn't seem to make much sense. Why not get the sale price/regular price in the SQL statement? Why not select just the desired product in the SQL statement? Also, I echo @OliGirling's comment.

Comment: @SloanThrasher thankyou very much for your comment. As you can tell I am pretty new to PHP (and coding in general). Is there any chance that you could give an answer to my post to outline what I could to improve? Thanks for taking the time to comment on my post either way

Comment: Edit your question, and add the table schema. Also, is the product id coming from a form field, or is it really coming from the session? If from the session, are there multiple ids?